# Take a screen shot of parts of the page that aren't visible

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

I want to make a screenshot of the page where I save the downloads. This page has many downloads and not all of them are visible in the visible area of the screen. If I want to see all of them I have to scroll down in the vertical scroll bar on the right side of the screen with the pad on the laptop.

How do I make a screenshot where I see everything I have on that screen from the beginning to the end including the part that is not seen?

Comment: Can you just print the web page and save it to a PDF (Print to PDF)? Seems like this is a pretty simple thing unless I am missing something...

Comment: There are many screenshot utilities & methods to capture parts of the page not visible. But that isn't really what you're describing. Those lists don't extend off the visible screen, they contain their own scrolling to display content outside of what is in its own box. You would need a utility that either captures scrolling or creates a huge virtual screen on which you expand the box to display everything, then a screenshot utility to capture it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a tool to do “scrolling capture.”

There are currently several tools out there that do it:

- SnagIt
- FastStone Capture
- Screenpresso

I’m sure there are more.

Answer (score 1):

You can only take a screen shot of what you can currently see on the screen. You can use Windows 7's built-in Snipping Tool (search the Start Menu for it) and take a screen shot, then move the list of downloads to show more of the downloads, then take another screen shot.

Repeat this as many times as necessary until you've captured all the information you need to save.

Comment: Thanks friend for the answer, I want to know if the procedure can be done in the Greenshot program which I use to make screenshots and I have tried in several ways to make a screenshot with several pages within the same folder or file either in Word or in any part of Windows 7 ultimate 64 bits which is the version that I have installed on my laptop and I could not. You could help me if you can do what you told me in Greenshot. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, any screen shot program, including Greenshot can be used. If you have a question about how to do something in Greenshot, please post a new question.